# XQuery fn:replace not behaving as expected

Tags: excel, xquery

I have an Excel worksheet in XML format which contains

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s127"><Data ss:Type="String">Replace Me</Data></Cell>
```

I want to replace @A01-Replace with a different string.  I'm using the XQuery's replace function like so:

```
let $excel := doc("document.xml")

let $test := "another string"

return replace($excel, "Replace Me", $test)
```

Before calling replace, the variable $excel is valid XML upon output.  However, when I output $excel after I call the replace function, all of the XML tags have been stripped, and $excel is a string with the content of the cells as its values.  I would like to keep the XML tags there.

What I expect is

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s127"><Data ss:Type="String">another string</Data></Cell>
```

However, I get

```
another string
```

All the XML tags are stripped out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fn:replace` is a simple String Manipulation Function from XQuery.

This function works with a String and not **node()*** types `data-type`.

```
let $replaced-str := fn:replace( $excel/Data/text(), "Replace Me", $test)
```

should return another string.

If you want to work with an XML document then you need to use 
`xdmp:node-replace` type function which is specific to MarkLogic XmlDatabase.

If you want a simple `XQuery/Xml/Memory` based `node-replace` then you can write a simple recursive replace method which accepts an XPath and re-creates a new node. Or 
check out [this MarkLogic-commons example](http://github.com/marklogic/commons/blob/master/memupdate/in-mem-update.xqy).